# Redux managing arrays of objects and finding nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm not sure what to name this, but basically I'm new to React and Redux and looking for a more correct/cleaner way to do this or just how to do this with my current set up.
I have a state that looks like this

```
--Character
---id
---name
---race
----id
----raceName
----traits
-----trait
------id
------name
------description
-----trait
------id
------name
------description
---classes
----class
-----id
-----className
-----classLevel
-----traits
------trait
-------id
-------name
-------description
------trait
-------id
-------name
-------description
----class
-----id
-----className
-----classLevel
-----traits
------trait
-------id
-------name
-------description
------trait
-------id
-------name
-------description
---traits
----trait
-----id
-----name
-----description
----trait
-----id
-----name
-----description
```

As you can see(hopefully) traits is an array of object TRAIT and classes is an array of object CLASS, in the end the whole state is quite a messy deal. I've read that I can somehow reference them by ID's but I'm not sure how if IDs are autogenerated.

So I kind of have two questions:

1. How do I simplify/flatten this structure if it even could be done?
2. If I can't simplify this structure is there anyway I can find a specific Trait with a specific ID without looping through all the objects that have property traits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can find `Trait` with a specific ID easily. Let know if this is what you are asking.

```
// Search in traits directly under Character.

const traitForId = this.state.Character.traits.find((trait) => {
   return trait.id = "<SPECIFIC_ID>"
})


// Search in the list of traits under each Class.

const classTraits = this.state.Character.classes.map((class) => class.traits).flat();
const classTraitsForId = classTraits.find((trait) => {
   return trait.id = "<SPECIFIC_ID>"
})
```

Find below recursive way to find a `Trait` irrespective of where it's present in the state.

```
function findTraitForId(state, specific_id){
 if(state.traits){
   const traitForId = state.traits.find((trait) => {
      return trait.id == specific_id
   });
   if(traitForId)
      return traitForId;
 }
 return Object.keys(state).filter((key) => key != 'traits').map((stateItem) => {
   return findTraitForId(state[stateItem], specific_id);
 }).flat();
}
```

Tried above function for the input

```
findTraitForId({'classes':[{traits: [{id: 1, name: "A"}, {id: 2, name: "AB"}]}, {traits: [{id: 3, name: "ABC"}, {id: 4, name: "ABCD"}]}], traits: [{id: 5, name: "ABCDE"}, {id: 6, name: "ABCDEF"}]}, 3)
```

which return

```
[{id: 3, name: "ABC"}]
```

Comment: sorry realized i didn't delete 1 and 2s after traits. trait1 and trait2 are also object TRAIT and I need to check the ones in classes as well I updated my question to show the correct version

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your ask. See if it makes sense.

Comment: Is there a way I can update that specific trait without knowing where in the tree it is located?

Comment: Possible. I have added a recursive way of doing it. It will scan all the nodes in the tree until the the trait is found.